# Pagination using REST API using Spring Boot and GBQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, pagination, microservices

I have Experience API endpoint which will give results as per limit and offset. My REST API calls the Big Query and get the data set as it has more than 500 records, I need to store product ids in cache so that I can use it in every pagination request for given limit and offset. Is there any alternative better solution for this kind of scneario?

Comment: please share some code too so that alternate solution can be suggested

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.